# How can I call prompt_toolkit from the tornado event loop?

Tags: python, tornado, prompt, toolkit

I am trying to use prompt_toolkit from an application that uses the tornado event loop, but I can not work out the correct way to add the prompt_toolkit prompt to the event loop.

The prompt_toolkit documentation has an example of using it in asyncio ([Asyncio Docs](http://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/building_prompts.html#prompt-in-an-asyncio-application)):

```
from prompt_toolkit.shortcuts import prompt_async

async def my_coroutine():
    while True:
        result = await prompt_async('Say something: ', patch_stdout=True)
        print('You said: %s' % result)
```

I have managed to make this work from the asyncio event loop:

```
import asyncio
l = asyncio.get_event_loop()
l.create_task(my_coroutine())
l.run_forever()

Say something: Hello
You said: Hello
```

However, I have failed to make it work from the tornado event loop. I have tried the following:

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
IOLoop.current().run_sync(my_coroutine)
```

This will issue the initial prompt but then appears to block the console.

I have also tried:

```
IOLoop.current().add_callback(my_coroutine)
IOLoop.current().start()
```

This does the same thing, but also produces the error message:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'my_coroutine' was never awaited
```

And I have tried:

```
IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(my_coroutine)
IOLoop.current().start()
```

I am clearly not understanding something here.

Can anyone throw any light on how this should be done?

I am using: Python 3.5.0, tornado 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

To use [Tornado's asyncio integration](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/asyncio.html), you must tell Tornado to use the asyncio event loop. Usually, that means doing this at the start of your app:

```
from tornado.platform.asyncio import AsyncIOMainLoop
AsyncIOMainLoop().install()
```